# How do I iterate over a request object and filter by a specific html tag

Tags: python, html, django, loops

Given the code below:

```
output=''
for k,v in request.POST.items():
    output+= k + ' '
```

This returns:

```
textarea4 _submit textarea2 csrfmiddlewaretoken textarea1 textarea3
```

However, I only want the `textarea` names. How can I filter the rest out?

Comment: Add a conditional to check if `k.startswith('textarea')`

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  I'll accept it if you reply as an Answer.

Comment: Made some slight grammatical edits. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try looking to see if each key starts with `textarea` instead?  Use the [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method for strings:

```
output = ''
for k in request.POST:
    if k.startswith('textarea'):
        output += k + ' '
```

However, to be more Pythonic, use the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method for strings:

```
output = ' '.join([k for k in request.POST if k.startswith('textarea')])
```

The above will join strings, or the keys in `request.POST` in our case, together in a list with spaces in between each key, provided that each key in `request.POST` starts with `textarea`.   I used a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to help me do this in one line.

Comment: @woodduck - Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could submit them all under the same name such as `textarea[]` then use  `request.POST.getlist('textarea')` to get the values.

Example form with three text area fields.:

```
<form>
    <textarea name='textarea[]'></textarea>
    <textarea name='textarea[]'></textarea>
    <textarea name='textarea[]'></textarea>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I like this option but could you show an example of how I can submit as a list?  I currently have <textarea name={{ x.id }}></textarea><input type="submit" value="submit" />

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of the html form.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Good to know for future reference but in my current case I can't use it because the name is actually wholly or partially an id number.

Comment: You can always put the id in a data attribute such as ```data-id="{{x.id}}"```